# How to call a function from HTML in Ionic 3?

Tags: html, ionic3, angular5

I'm calling the plot() function from HTML, but that function is getting called multiple times. It should be called only once when the condition is true.My plot() function is getting called several times before getting plotted to Map.

```js
 plot(){
    var self = this;
    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) =>   {
 
      let lat = self.lat;
      let lng= self.lng;
       console.log(lat);
       console.log(lng);
      let mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
        zoom: 17,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }
      this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);
      this.addMarker();
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
  addMarker(){
    console.log("coming in marker");
    var self=this;
    let lat = self.lat;
    let lng= self.lng;
    var markerPos = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: self.map,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position:markerPos,
    
 });
 console.log(marker.position);
 let content = "<h4>Information!</h4>";          
 this.addInfoWindow(marker, content);
}
addInfoWindow(marker, content){
 
  let infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: content
  });

 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', () => {
   infoWindow.open(this.map, marker);
 });
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 80%;margin-right:3%;" *ngIf="chatMessage.types=='checkin' " class="message {{chatMessage.type === 'message_response' ? 'right' : 'left'}} img">
    <img *ngIf="chatMessage.userIcon=='mji247'" src="assets/mji.png">
    <img *ngIf="chatMessage.userIcon==''" src="assets/user.png">
    <p style="font-size: 12px;white-space: pre-wrap;">{{this.chatMessage.msg.name}}:</p>
 
    <div #map id="map" style="height: 200px;width: 225px;float: right;margin-right: 22px;border-radius: 5%;">
        {{plot()}} 
    </div>
    <p *ngIf="chatMessage.type != 'message_response'" style="overflow: auto;text-align: right;margin-left: 12%;font-size: 12px;white-space: pre-wrap;">{{this.chatMessage.msg.date}}</p>
    <p *ngIf="chatMessage.type == 'message_response'" style="overflow: auto;font-size: 12px;white-space: pre-wrap;">{{this.chatMessage.msg.date}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems like an XY problem... When exactly do you need the function executed?

Comment: I'm sending diffrent types for ChatMessage.types. Iwant this function to run exactly when ChatMessage.types=='checkin' . In this type I'm getting the lattitude and longitude value which I need to plot when types==checkin

Answer (score 0):

```
<a class=“href-a” [href]=“getImgContent(request?.mobile)“></a>
getImgContent = (number) =>{
   console.log(number );
   return 'sms:' + number + ';
 }
```

Comment: You should provide an explanation of what you code does at least